# Build many dockerfiles on jenkins project

Tags: testing, jenkins, docker, automation

I have some task:

I have github repostiroy with folder "**docker**" and in this folder have many sub-folders with names (**app1**, **app2**, **app3**, etc.) with only **Dockerfile** in subfolder.

Sometimes i add new subfolder with name **app50** and i want to Jenkins build automatically this new **dockerfile** and if all ok push new images to private docker registry.

How I can automate to select sub-folder, enter to him and run docker build ? with cutsom tag and name.

For example i upload new folder "**app70-1.2.3**" with **Dockerfile**. Jenkins need enter to folder "**docker/app70-1.2.3**" and run "`docker build -t app70:1.2.3 .`"

Answer (score 1):

I am using similar approach and the simplest way to achieve this in your case could be via [Feature branching strategy](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html). Just use your branch as folder name and then run something like this as Jenkins (shell) build step:

```
cd ${GIT_BRANCH}
docker build -t ${GIT_BRANCH} .
```